# How do I properly align an outdoor light fixture?

Tags: outdoor, light, junction-box

I was trying to install an outdoor light this afternoon. Unfortunately the outlet box is interfering with the mounting bracket. I looked around at a few different lights and it looks like I would have the same issue with them as well.

The mounting holes in the outlet box are horizontal. It appears the installation instructions are expecting these mounting holes to be at an angle. The screws that mount to the light fixture are too long and are hitting the outlet box. Does the outlet box need to be rotated, or am I missing something obvious?

[**Here are the light fixture installation instructions.**](https://www.costco.com/wcsstore/CostcoUSBCCatalogAssetStore/Attachment/AL-2163esf01172017.pdf)

[image]

Comment: Can you post photos/instructions for the light fixture?

Comment: I edited it in.

Answer (score 2):

The mounting bracket is designed so that you can rotate the fixture, no matter how the outlet box is mounted.

[image]

The mounting bracket screws hold the lower portion of the bracket securely in place. Before securing the lower portion, be sure to insert the longer fixture screws. They need to face outward so that you can secure the hex nuts to them. If you thread the hex nuts down onto the fixture screws, the screws won't fall off while you are securing the lock nuts. See Figure 2...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you. The fixture screws interfere with the outlet box mounting holes. It appears the bracket is not meant to have both the mounting side and the fixture side be horizontal. Even threading the fixture screws through the mounting bracket slots didn't work, as the outlet box mounting holes are in the way.

Comment: Would shorter screw help with that? Many electrical wire stripper tools have a part that allows you to cut these screws to length.See the illustration here: https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/20873/what-is-the-purpose-of-these-holes-on-my-wire-stripper

Comment: Jeremy, I have added another photo that might help.